# Adding attributes to all html tags

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to add `id="draggable"` attributes to all tags.

For example -

`<img src="http://sample.jpg">` should change to `<img src="http://sample.jpg" id="draggable" >`

`<p>abcd</p>` should change to `<p id="draggable">abcd</p>`

This should apply to all tags except `<HTML><HEAD><script><style>`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Putting the same id for a bunch of elements on the same page is not a sound plan. Ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: adding same id to different elements is not a good approach...go for class..

Comment: Yes got it ..thank you so much. Now I am using class attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class instead of Ids

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
elems.setAttribute("class","draggable");
```

Answer (score 0):

ID(s):
Each element should only have one ID
Each page can only have one element with that ID
CLass(s):
You can use mutliple classes on one element.
You can use the same class on multiple elements

Comment: Yes agreed - I am using class attribute now

Answer (score 0):

Adding same `id` to all the HTML elements is not a good way. Better to have same class name. Dynamically, if you want to add same class to all the elements, you can do something like below

```
$('#parent').find('*').addClass('draggable');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/663m8qyd/

```
<div id='parent'>
    <p>ABC</p>
    <img src='http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif' alt="Smiley face"/>
    <div id='child'>
        <div id='child1'>test1</div>
        <div id='child2'>test2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To add `draggable` class to all the elements inside `parent` div, find each element and add respective class.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Its not tagged jQuery

Comment: @RahulB...Agreed!..Although by that way.. regex tag doesn't seem logical too.. ;)